# Compressing a string in R

Tags: r

I have a large sequence of strings containing only the following characters

```
"M", "D", "A"
```

such as:

```
 "M" "M" "A" "A" "D" "D" "M" "D" "A"
```

and I would like to compress it to:

```
M2A2D2M1D1A1
```

in R. Googling has led me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647520/java-compressing-strings) (a java solution) but before implementing it, it would be interesting to check if I can find something ready online. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R function `rle()` is your friend.

```
testVector <- sample(c("M", "D", "A"), 20, replace=T)
res <- rle(testVector)
compressedString <- paste(res$values, res$lengths, collapse = "", sep = "")
```